# Using an unmerged branch from StatsModels for Anaconda

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, statsmodels

I am interested in using a statistical test from StatsModels, one that is not available in the default Anaconda StatsModels folder on my drive.

See this [blog](https://rlhick.people.wm.edu/stories/econ_407_notes_heckman.html), which as some point mentions, almost casually: ``We can estimate a Two-Step Heckman Model in Python using an [unmerged](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/92ea62232fd63c7b60c60bee4517ab3711d906e3/statsmodels/regression/heckman.py) branch from StatsModels (this replicates the Stata two-step results).''

Yeah right.

My question: how to accomplish this?

StatsModels packages reside in three locations on my drive, see below the folders for `linear_model.py` as an example.

```
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py
~/anaconda3/pkgs/statsmodels-0.10.0-py37hdd07704_0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py
~/anaconda3/pkgs/statsmodels-0.10.1-py37hdd07704_0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py
```

I dread to just copy the `heckman.py` file in any of them and risk breaking Anaconda.